# Remove all validation constraints in child class properties

Tags: symfony

I have problem with clearing all validation constraint that extend from super class. Below is my code

**User.php**

```
  * @var string
  * @ORM\Column(type="text", unique=true)
  * @Assert\NotBlank()
  * @Assert\NotNull()
  * @AdminAssert\MyCustomValidation
  */
 protected $phoneNumber;
```

In Admin.php I wrote code something like below

**class Admin extends User**

```
  * @var string
  * @ORM\Column(type="text", unique=true)
  */
 protected $phoneNumber;
```

I want to remove all validation constraints but can't remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For disabling the validation of a form you can set the `validation_groups` option to `false`, as described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#disabling-validation) in the doc.

In your case you can check the class data ([as described here in the doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#groups-based-on-the-submitted-data)) for disabling or not the form validation, as example:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'validation_groups' => function (FormInterface $form) {
            $data = $form->getData();

            if ($data instanceof Admin) {
                return;
            }

            return array('Default');
        },
    ));
}
```

Hovenever in your code i see a a custom validation on admin validation, if so consider to use the validation groups.

Hope this help

Comment: Erb, my bad, I put wrong naming convention. Any way it works fine me, Thank @Matteo, but I just change something in your code like this $data instanceof Admin and return; (without false) not really sure why false doesn't work.

Comment: hi @vibol you are welcome! Feel free to edit my answer with the correct working code.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Admin class "extends" or inherits from the User class, you'll need to remove the constraints in User like so:

```
  * @var string
  * @ORM\Column(type="text", unique=true)
  */
 protected $phoneNumber;
```

Hopefully, that's all you need?

Comment: Make sure you run from your Symfony root directory this command: `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` after you make those changes

Comment: I ran it, but still problem

Comment: Truly, I can't remove validation from User class, because it was inherited by many classes, just admin class that don't need it